# Where did the grunt min task go?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I watched many tutorials on grunt where some **min** task was used. I couldn't find any plugins referring to similar task. I would guess that devs have updated it and renamed to **uglify** am i right? And another issue i had was the installation of grunt. Can it still be installed globally, or should i install grunt-cli globally and grunt locally in order to use it for my local projects??

This:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
```

doesn't work for me,
only:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Is the first method deprecated?

## Edit:

Here is the video i'm refering to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3Sqljpr-Vc

Comment: yes, min also mentioned in this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-optimize-your-wordpress-development-workflow--wp-26119 which confused me too.

Comment: Here is [another tutorial](https://gist.github.com/balupton/3898915) that refers to the 'min' task. It links to [this grunt doc](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/docs/task_min.md) that also refers to the 'min' task while also specifying uglify. But I have also been able to get 'min' to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many [different min libraries](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/minify) including these by the core grunt team:

- grunt-contrib-cssmin   (grunt-contrib-mincss is the older version)
- grunt-contrib-htmlmin
- grunt-contrib-imagemin
- grunt-contrib-uglify  <== for js minification

It is likely the one you are referring to is the uglify plugin, but hard to tell without knowing which tutorial you were watching.

As to installing, the second form is correct for grunt 4.x as described in the [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

Comment: it was used to minify .js files. i also think that it probably was the  **uglify** plugin. what bothers me is that they using **min** as a target. i'm just new to grunt and wanted to know if there was another good plugin i wasn't aware of. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I saw the same tutorial and I couldn't found min task too. 'min' seems using uglify internally so you can use uglify directly.

decalre task in `gruntfile.js`

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
    src: foo.js,
    dest: foo.min.js
  }
}
```

load plugin

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

and run

```
$ grunt uglify
```