# Task 'min' not found

Tags: gruntjs

I've just set up Grunt for my project and I'm trying to run `min` task but I get the error:

> Task 'min' not found

Here is my `gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    min: {
        dist: {
            src: "calculator/add.js",
            dest: "add.min.js"
        }
    }
  });
};
```

What could be wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be called `Gruntfile` not `gruntfile.js`?

Comment: this file was created when I installed grunt, so I suppose its naming is correct

Comment: Not sure what plugin you think is providing the min task. Perhaps this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18431770/557612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the **npm** module containing the task in to grunt. Update your Gruntfile so it looks like the example below.

Please note, that you need to have the correct name for the npm module to be loaded in. Although the grunt task may be called `min`, this is probably not the case for the npm module. I referenced `grunt-example-min` in the example file below, so be sure to update this to the correct name.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    min: {
        dist: {
            src: "calculator/add.js",
            dest: "add.min.js"
        }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-example-min');

  grunt.registerTask('default',['min']);
};
```